# Send only part of headers (preload / prefetch)

Tags: php, http-headers

Our PHP-system generates webpages like this:

```
1. [Init]
2. [Do some DB-queries and calculations, might take some seconds, might end up in sending a 301 or 404]
3. [Output results]
```

Now I want to speed up the pages by preloading css, fonts and js-files. It would be ideal if I could send headers like this:

```
1. [Init]
header("Link: </style.css>; rel=preload; as=style", false);
2. [Do some DB-queries and calculations, might take some seconds, might end up in sending a 301 or 404]
3. [Output results]
```

but the preload-header is sent only when output started in step 3 - so there is not much gain in speed. So I tried:

```
1. [Init]
header("Link: </style.css>; rel=preload; as=style", false);
flush();
2. [Do some DB-queries and calculations, might take some seconds, might end up in sending a 301 or 404]
3. [Output results]
```

Wow, this really speeds things up! But well, sending a 301 or 404 header in step 2 ends up in the message:

**Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...

So I need to put it there:

```
1. [Init]
2. [Do some DB-queries and calculations, might take some seconds, might end up in sending a 301 or 404]
header("Link: </style.css>; rel=preload; as=style", false);
3. [Output results]
```

which doesn't bring a big advantage in speed, because the big time-consuming things are done in step 2.

Q: Since headers are transferred line by line from the webserver to the browser I was wondering if there is a way to send the preload-header to the browser and a 301-header some seconds afterwards like:

```
1. [Init]
header("Link: </style.css>; rel=preload; as=style", false);
send_part_of_headers();
2. [Do some DB-queries and calculations, might take some seconds, might end up in sending a 301 or 404]
3. [Output results]
```

Comment: _“Now I want to speed up the pages by preloading css, fonts and js-files.”_ - assuming these are static resources, and they are delivered with appropriate caching instructions, this would only affect the first page load anyway then … on all follow-up pages the user visits, these should be in the local cache then already. Is it really still worth the effort under these conditions? The problem with your loading times would have to be pretty big, before that becomes justifiable, I think.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on speeding other things up as well, but why waste time and let the user wait? You are right with caching, but especially the first page load might decide if a user stays on a page or leaves it, so every ms counts ;-)

Comment: If any initial page load can need several seconds for the system to determine, whether it has actual content to serve, or wants to redirect somewhere else - ins’t that pretty broken architecture to begin with? Then it might make more sense that you load a “skeleton document” first, and then do the time-consuming stuff in a background request triggered by client-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [very first line of the HTTP response is the status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-6.1), e.g.:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
```

All other headers follow this line. So, no, it's impossible to output some `Link` headers first and *then* send the status code. If it was any other header, then purely from the perspective of HTTP, it would be possible to send some headers first and others later (whether your web server would cooperate there is a different story); but the status code cannot be deferred.

As an alternative approach, you may want to look into HTTP/2 and sending those CSS files in advance already. Or, of course, speed up that database operation in some way.

Comment: Thanks, this explains why "splitting" the headers couldn't work! 

My webhoster already offers HTTP/2. Do you have any example code how to "send" files in advance in PHP? I could only find this example: https://blog.cloudflare.com/using-http-2-server-push-with-php/ but this is what I'm already doing.

Comment: Yeah, if the web server requires that PHP set a Link header to trigger HTTP/2 push, that obviously defeats the purpose. It really depends on the web server, whether you can configure it in some other way deeper down in its configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the [103 Early Hints](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8297) status code. Also [detailed on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/103) and [this blog post](https://evertpot.com/http/103-early-hints).

This sends an additional message before the main result with your preload link

Unfortunately support of this, on both server sending side, and browser receiving side is incredibly poor. And some applications will bulk when they effectively get back two HTTP messages instead of the usual one.

Your best option for now is probably to separate the message into two - a basic index.html “shell” and an API call that loads the data into that shell.